# Passing variables from Apple Shortcuts to AppleScript and returning the result

Tags: applescript, sirishortcuts

I'm trying to pass a string from Shortcuts to AppleScript, where AppleScript should truncate the string and return it back to Shortcuts, but I'm having difficulties. Any help would be appreciated Here's what I've got so far:

Shortcuts String to AppleScript, return Truncated results

[image: 1]

I've tried using several methods to pass the text... I can pass original string through the applescript, and return the original text, but the truncated text is the problem.

Comment: Note that the input to the AppleScript `run` handler is a _list_.

Comment: You can avoid the AppleScript call entirely by using the Match shortcut and match against the pattern "^.{1,500}" (without the quotes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the output of an AppleScript directly by typing the returned variable.

For example that Shortcut uses the `micState` in the notification action. When you type it, it will automatically autocomplete:
[image: mute-unmute-mic-image]